# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on function return

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I am stumped at a bug in my code where I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when a function call completes and exits the function. It's quite a long piece of code, so I will try to abbreviate it. I have a class like this:

```
class BigClass {
public:
    // some class members
    HelperClass object1; // this class describes a particular type of graph
    HelperClass object2;
    BigClass(int n, int m, long double epsilon,
             long double numerical_accuracy_tol, ...); // calls constructor for obj1, 2   
    void GenerateInstance(); // Populates graphs for obj 1 and 2
    // some more stuff
}
```

`GenerateInstance()` looks like:

```
void BigClass::GenerateInstance() {
    // generate matrix m1
    object1.PopulateGraph(m1);
    // generate some matrix m2
    object2.PopulateGraph(m2);
}
```

When I run this, I can an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. If I debug step by step, it runs though `object2.PopulateGraph(m2)`, but when it exits from it, I get the crash. The same thing happens even if remove all the code from PopulateGraph() and just have print out a test message, or even if I also delete the parts of the code that generate the matrices or populate object1. The only way to make it not give the error is if I run

```
void BigClass::GenerateInstance() {
    // everything commented out
    object2.PopulateGraph(); // Populate graph empty
}
```

`HelperClass` looks like

```
class HelperClass {
    public:
    int num_partitions_;
    long double numerical_accuracy_tolerance_;
    vector<SomeOtherObject> subgraphs_;
    HelperClass(int num_partitions, long double numerical_accuracy_tolerance);
}


HelperClass::HelperClass(int num_partitions, long double numerical_accuracy_tolerance) {
    num_partitions_ = num_partitions;
    numerical_accuracy_tolerance_ = numerical_accuracy_tolerance;
}
```

the `subgraph_` member gets populated by `PopulateGraph(<vector<vector<long double> > m1)`.

Any idea of why this is happening? I'm not doing any memory allocation of my own, and since the bug occurs even if I comment out most of my code, I don't think it could be that... Thanks for any feedback you may have.

Comment: You are probably writing outside the stack of the functions you call.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, but I'm afraid I'm not proficient enough to understand what you mean. Are you saying that inside PopulateGraph() I'm writing outside of the stack? Wouldn't it then stop giving the error when I commented everything inside PopulateGraph() except some print statement?

Comment: @dfc02138 - depends on the print statement ;)

Comment: I mean one that just prints text, not any variable!

Comment: Seeing the members and ctor/dtor of `HelperClass` may prove beneficial. Please include the class def and the constructor and destructor in your question.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `PopulateGraph()` function? Also, where are `m1` and `m2` declared? It is very difficult for people on this site to help you without looking at critical parts of your code.